# MVC 6 Post action parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC 6 application and a separate MVC 6 WebAPI service.

I send an object from the application using this code:
[image]

This is the View part of it:
[image]

The client sends it to the WebAPI service:
[image]

Where the parameter is null:

[image]

In the Fiddler log I get 0 as Content-Length:

[image]

What else should I set?

Comment: I don't think the binding works with dynamic objects. Try updating your webapi action so the argument is a strongly typed object instead of a dynamic object. (Which would be a better idea imho even if you could use dynamic arguments)

Comment: I have changed it to Blog object, but it does not work. The binding looks for specific object types or checks only the named fields with reflection? I ask this, because I have 2 types of Blog (one on the server side and one on the client side).

Comment: Instead of doing the convert yourself to json, have you tried using `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", blog)` ?

Comment: Also, is that Fiddler screen shot showing the content length as zero from the form post back, not the API request? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: About Fiddler, yes, you are right, it is not the API request, I misread it.

Comment: Yes, the binding will use reflection. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding). If I am not mistaken, a complex object like your `Blog` type would use the [`MutableObjectModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/MutableObjectModelBinder.cs).

Comment: @CraigH I can't use PostAsJsonAsync because I can only use DNX compatible libraries, so I can't add WebAPI.Client NuGet pack which contains that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very important to set the encoding and media type of the StringContent. If I could use `PostAsJsonAsync` that would probably take care of this part - unfortunately I can't use it in DNX.

So this is the proper code of the client:

```
  string content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blog);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
```